# Access MDI child control from MDI parent control

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a `MDIParent` form,`MDIChild` form and normal form called `form1`,`form1` is inherited from MDIChild and,form one has textbox called textBox1,in Parent form i have two buttons New and Save, when i click New child form should be loaded and when I click save a message box should be pop-up with `textbox1.text` value ,the problem is message box is pop-up with-out `textbox1` text value

i m using bellow code to load child form inside the parent form.

```
public partial class MDIParent1 : Form
{
    MdiClient mdi = null;
    string fname;

    public MDIParent1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is MdiClient)
            {
                mdi = (MdiClient)c;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and i use to call to the load form function using bellow code[clicking on new button]

```
private void ShowNewForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    load_form(new Form1());
}
```

load form function is

```
private void load_form(object form)
{
    foreach (Form f in mdi.MdiChildren)
    {
        f.Close();

    }
    if (form == null)
        return;
    ((Form)form).MdiParent = this;
    ((Form)form).Show();
    ((Form)form).AutoScroll = true;
    fname = ((Form)form).Name;
}
```

and my form is loading..in save button `onClick` function , i call to the form1 function called `getdata()`

```
public void getdata()
{
    messageBox.show(textBox1.text);
}
```

Comment: I really have to point out that your casting is completely un-necessary. `object form` should be `Form form`.

Comment: Thank you ,Simon Whitehead but my problem is still not solved,plz can any one help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public partial class MDIChild : Form
    {
        public virtual string GetMessage()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }    
    }

    public class Form2 : MDIChild
    {
        TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();

        public override string  GetMessage()
        {
            return textBox1.Text;
        }
    }


    public partial class MDIParent1 : Form
    {
        private MdiClient mdi = null;
        private string fname;
        private MDIChild currentActiveChild;

        public MDIParent1()
        {
            base.InitializeComponent();
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                if (c is MdiClient)
                {
                    mdi = (MdiClient) c;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void ShowNewForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentActiveChild = new Form2();
            load_form(currentActiveChild);
        }

        public void getdata()
        {
            if (currentActiveChild != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(currentActiveChild.GetMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Brother,I have a textbox in my form1 which i add it in design time ,now this code create new textbox in run time there is some confuse using these text boxes , i want to get my design time  text box value

Comment: Implementation of GetMessage() in form1 is at your hand, if you have a reference to design time text box, then you may change the implementation of GetMessage() based up on using the the reference. if suffering difficulties send a full code, i will try to help you

Comment: friend im new to this forum i don't know how to send code to you please tell it to me?